# Opening new browser tab with angular 4 keep parent tab unresponsive

Tags: angular

I am trying to open new browser tab with specific URL. Once it is open, the parent tab becomes unresponsive (no scrollbar etc..)

Other issue is, until the new tab is fully loaded, the parent tab keeps blank.

```
clickOnProduct(){
 this.searchService.selectProduct(product).subscribe(
  response => {
    if (response.returnData) {
     // generate url based on response 

     window.open(url, '_blank');
  });
 }
```

Comment: More info needed

Comment: @Sam see updated question

Comment: The closest code I have is along these lines: 

 var windowSize = "width=" + window.innerWidth + ",height=" + window.innerHeight + ",scrollbars=no";
    
    var win = window.open(url, 'popup', windowSize);

    if (win) {
      //Browser has allowed it to be opened
      if (!win.focus()) {
        var win = window.open(url, '_blank');
      }
     else {
        win.focus()
      }

Perhaps you could try something similar. Not sure why you are seeing an issue here. This generally works fine, but as you can see I used a few workarounds for mobile etc.

Comment: If i use window.open outside the subscribe method, it works. But I need it inside.

Comment: I can't see why it's not working, I do it within subscribe and it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After adding intermediate component between product selection and next step, this issue is resolved. So the intermediate component handled the actual item selection request.